# Change SQL query based on array elements

Tags: php, sql

I can't get any solution for my script. I'm trying to change my SQL query based on what is in the array. I have an jQuery AJAX call that calls a PHP script retrieving information from the database based on passed data through the AJAX call.
I have 5 checkboxes with different values. On each checkbox click it stores a number from 1 to 5 into the array. When uncheck the box the number disappear from the array. This array is passing through the AJAX call on each checkbox click. The problem comes here - The array is successfully passing to the PHP script file, but I need based on what is inside the array to change my SQL query. When there are for example ('1', '5') in the array i want the SQL query to retrieve information with a condition "WHERE `column` = "1" AND `column` = '5'", but I can't create it logically. That's what I've made so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `reviews` 
        WHERE `review_website_id`='" . $getQfetch['website_id'] . "' ";

if(in_array("1", $_GET['stars'])) {
    $sql .= " AND `review_stars` = '1'";
}
if(in_array("2", $_GET['stars'])) {
    $sql .= " AND `review_stars` = '2'";
}
if(in_array("3", $_GET['stars'])) {
    $sql .= " AND `review_stars` = '3'";
}
if(in_array("4", $_GET['stars'])) {
    $sql .= " AND `review_stars` = '4'";
}
if(in_array("5", $_GET['stars'])) {
    $sql .= " AND `review_stars` = '5'";
}

$sql .= " ORDER BY CAST(review_id AS SIGNED) DESC";
```

The `$_GET['stars']` parameter is the array containing the values from 1-5. I need the SQL query to retrieve information either the array contain values `1`, `5`.. or `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` but when there are multiple checkbox selections the query goes wrong.

Comment: You need to use OR not AND x cannot be both 1 and 2 :)

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Use a parameterized query and just use `$_GET['stars']`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query builds this:

```
... AND review_stars = 1 AND review_stars = 2 AND review_stars = 3 ...
```

Obviously, `review_stars` can't be both 1 *AND* 2 at the same time.

You want this:

```
... AND (review_stars = 1 OR review_stars = 2 OR review_stars = 3) ...
```

Or, equivalently:

```
... AND review_stars IN (1, 2, 3) ...
```

Also note, your code is likely vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, always use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your array to a comma delimited string.

`$values = implode(', ', $_GET['stars']);`

`$sql .= " AND review_stars in ($values)";`